# Running code inside executable memory

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, x86-64, kernel-module

I have this code that will write some bytecode into an executable memory and (try to) run it. Anyways, I'm not getting anything else than kernel oops, and I'm not sure what exactly is wrong.

I "translated" the 4 ASM instructions at the beggining of the code to their equivalent in bytecode using `as`.

Btw, the `__asm__ __volatile__` block works as expected.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

static int __init hello_init(void){

    int64_t ret;
    char *fmt = "\n\n\n%s\n\n\n";
    char *s = "Hello world!";

    void (*test)(void);

    unsigned char *op_1 = "\x48\x8B\x3C\x25";
    unsigned char *op_2 = "\x48\x8B\x34\x25";
    unsigned char *op_3 = "\x48\x8B\x04\x25\x02\x00\x00\x00";
    unsigned char *call = "\xE8\x00\x00\x00";
    unsigned char *ret_call = "\xC3";

    unsigned int pos = 0;

    /*
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "movq %1, %%rdi;"
        "movq %0, %%rsi;"
        "movq $2, %%rax;"

        "call printk;"

        :
        : "m" (s), "m" (fmt)
        :
    );
    */

    unsigned char *bytecode = __vmalloc(
        strlen(op_1) + sizeof(void *) +
        strlen(op_2) + sizeof(void *) +
        strlen(op_3) +
        strlen(call) + sizeof(void *) +
        strlen(ret_call),
        GFP_KERNEL, PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC
    );

    //movq <fmt>, %%rdi
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, op_1, strlen(op_1));
    pos += strlen(op_1);
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, &fmt, sizeof(void *));
    pos += sizeof(void *);

    //movq <s>, %%rsi
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, op_2, strlen(op_2));
    pos += strlen(op_2);
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, &s, sizeof(void *));
    pos += sizeof(void *);

    //movq 2, %%rax
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, op_3, strlen(op_3));
    pos += strlen(op_3);

    //call printk
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, call, strlen(call));
    pos += strlen(call);
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, &printk, sizeof(void *));
    pos += sizeof(void *);

    //ret
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, ret_call, strlen(ret_call));

    test = bytecode;

    test();

    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_cleanup(void){}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_cleanup);
```

My question is what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I updated my code based on the suggestions. This is the new version and the kernel oops.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

static int __init hello_init(void){

    int64_t ret;
    char *fmt = "\n\n\n%s\n\n\n";
    char *s = "Hello world!";

    void (*test)(void);

    unsigned char op_1[] = { 0x48, 0x8B, 0x3C, 0x25 }; //movq <addr>, %rdi
    unsigned char op_2[] = { 0x48, 0x8B, 0x34, 0x25 }; //movq <addr>, %rsi
    unsigned char op_3[] = { 0x48, 0x8B, 0x04, 0x25, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }; //movq 2, %rax
    unsigned char call[] = { 0xE8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }; //call <printk addr>
    unsigned char ret_call[] = { 0xC3 }; //<ret>

    unsigned int pos = 0;

    /*
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "movq %1, %%rdi;"
        "movq %0, %%rsi;"
        "movq $2, %%rax;"

        "call printk;"

        :
        : "m" (s), "m" (fmt)
        :
    );
    */

    void *bytecode = __vmalloc(
        sizeof(op_1) + sizeof(void *) +
        sizeof(op_2) + sizeof(void *) +
        sizeof(op_3) +
        sizeof(call) + sizeof(void *) +
        sizeof(ret_call),
        GFP_KERNEL, PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC
    );

    //movq <fmt>, %%rdi
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, op_1, sizeof(op_1));
    pos += sizeof(op_1);
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, &fmt, sizeof(void *));
    pos += sizeof(void *);

    //movq <s>, %%rsi
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, op_2, sizeof(op_2));
    pos += sizeof(op_2);
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, &s, sizeof(void *));
    pos += sizeof(void *);

    //movq 2, %%rax
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, op_3, sizeof(op_3));
    pos += sizeof(op_3);

    //call printk
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, call, sizeof(call));
    pos += sizeof(call);
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, &printk, sizeof(void *));
    pos += sizeof(void *);

    //ret
    memcpy(bytecode + pos, ret_call, sizeof(ret_call));

    test = bytecode;

    test();

    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_cleanup(void){}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_cleanup);
```

Kernel oops:

```
[   96.439303] hello: module license 'unspecified' taints kernel.
[   96.441001] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP 
[   96.441009] Modules linked in: hello(POF+) snd_hrtimer(F) vboxsf(OF) vboxvideo(OF) drm bnep rfcomm bluetooth joydev(F) snd_intel8x0 snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus snd_pcm(F) snd_page_alloc(F) snd_seq_midi(F) snd_seq_midi_event(F) snd_rawmidi(F) snd_seq(F) snd_seq_device(F) snd_timer(F) ppdev(F) snd(F) parport_pc(F) mac_hid psmouse(F) vboxguest(OF) i2c_piix4 microcode(F) soundcore(F) serio_raw(F) lp(F) parport(F) vesafb(F) hid_generic usbhid hid ahci(F) libahci(F) e1000(F)
[   96.441032] CPU 0 
[   96.441043] Pid: 2300, comm: insmod Tainted: PF          O 3.8.0-29-generic #42-Ubuntu innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox
[   96.441051] RIP: 0010:[<ffffc90000182008>]  [<ffffc90000182008>] 0xffffc90000182007
[   96.441058] RSP: 0018:ffff880039a2de08  EFLAGS: 00010282
[   96.441066] RAX: ffffc90000182000 RBX: ffffffffa017e018 RCX: ffffc90000182000
[   96.441074] RDX: 8948559066666666 RSI: ffffc90000182000 RDI: 0a0a0a73250a0a0a
[   96.441082] RBP: ffff880039a2de10 R08: 0000000000000163 R09: 0000000000000001
[   96.441086] R10: 000000000000362a R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffffffa002e000
[   96.441094] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: ffffffffa017e000
[   96.441102] FS:  00007f83ffea9740(0000) GS:ffff88003fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   96.441110] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
[   96.441118] CR2: 00007fa90d1c2d20 CR3: 0000000038230000 CR4: 00000000000006f0
[   96.441133] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[   96.441238] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[   96.441246] Process insmod (pid: 2300, threadinfo ffff880039a2c000, task ffff880038802e80)
[   96.441254] Stack:
[   96.441261]  ffffffffa002e088 ffff880039a2de40 ffffffff8100215a ffffffffa017e018
[   96.441269]  ffffffffa017e050 ffff880039a2def0 0000000000000001 ffff880039a2dee0
[   96.441277]  ffffffff810bff59 ffffffff810bbbc0 ffff880035eace48 ffffffff00000001
[   96.441285] Call Trace:
[   96.441310]  [<ffffffffa002e088>] ? hello_init+0x88/0x1000 [hello]
[   96.441326]  [<ffffffff8100215a>] do_one_initcall+0x12a/0x180
[   96.441344]  [<ffffffff810bff59>] load_module+0xef9/0x1560
[   96.441357]  [<ffffffff810bbbc0>] ? unset_module_init_ro_nx+0x80/0x80
[   96.441373]  [<ffffffff810c0685>] sys_init_module+0xc5/0xf0
[   96.441389]  [<ffffffff816d561d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
[   96.441393] Code: <ff> ff ff ff 48 8b 34 25 2d d0 17 a0 ff ff ff ff 48 8b 04 25 02 00 
[   96.441408] RIP  [<ffffc90000182008>] 0xffffc90000182007
[   96.441419]  RSP <ffff880039a2de08>
[   96.441427] ---[ end trace 157c8f367de5a7f1 ]---
```

Comment: The obvious question is: Have you checked the dissasembly at the target memory?

Comment: Memory word/byte alignment may be an issue.

Comment: @Devolus Im not sure what you're asking exactly. Can you explain yourself a little bit further, please?

Comment: You are allocating a block and copy the code there. So the first thing I would check is, to see in the debugger if the dissassembly of that copied code is what I expect it to be.

Comment: @Devolus I'm not really sure how to do that as this is a kernel module.

Comment: http://elinux.org/Debugging_The_Linux_Kernel_Using_Gdb

Comment: Why don't you try doing this in user space before you do it in the kernel? The principles will all be the same, and debugging will be much easier.

Comment: `unsigned char *call = "\xE8\x00\x00\x00";` looks a bit suspicious, as if it is missing a displacement.  Are you **sure** that is a correct opcode? (And for that matter, that it will work if moved relative to its target?) Where did you get it from?

Comment: Additionally, you cannot use null-terminated strings with binary data containing the byte value 0 which it itself a null, at least not if you want to use the strlen() function!  Why don't you define an unsigned char array with initializers consisting of all the opcodes?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I got that output out from ```echo -e "<asm code here>" | as -o /dev/null -64 -al -msyntax=att```. You're right, strlen() will give wrong results when used with \x00. I'll try the array way.

Comment: I still don't like the zeros in the displacement(?) field of the call instruction, it looks as if you grabbed opcodes from something that was not yet fully linked.  How is this code supposed to know the address of `printk` anyway?  And if that is a displacement, do you realize that the value will need to change when you move the opcode to a different memory location?

Comment: @ChrisStratton the opcode (generated by ```as```) doesn't know the address of any of the values I'm using, nor the address of ```printk```, but that's why lines 47, 53, and 63 are for. I haven't thought about the second thing thou.

Comment: You appear to be writing absolute addresses rather than displacements.  Is that the correct addressing mode for these opcodes?  And is the portion of the opcodes you are writing out the portion that should precede the addresses, or are you in effect writing the address fields twice?  It would be really helpful if you could use a breakpoint debugger (kgdb??) to examine the created code in memory right as you would begin executing it.  Or maybe you can make a userspace equivalent which is easier to experiment with, and then apply lessons learned to a kernel mode version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `call` instruction is not encoded correctly.

The `call` instruction consists of a single `E8` byte and a 32-bit relative displacement (which is 32 bits even in 64-bit mode).
This displacement is the offset from the start of the instruction that follows the `call` to the destination address.
For example, in the following code:

```
0xffffffff12345678  E8 73 88 88 78  call printk
0xffffffff1234567d  C3              ret
...
printk:
0xffffffff8abcdef0  ...             ...
```

the displacement is `0xffffffff8abcdef0 - 0xffffffff1234567d = 0x78888873`.

If the displacement does not fit into 32 bits, you have to use an indirect call.

Comment: Interesting! Is it possible that the distance(difference) between the address of the function and ```E8``` is bigger than the maximum value that can be represented in a 32bit value? If so, how is that handled? And also, if that situation could happen, how likely is it to happen?

Comment: See the last sentence. If it is possible at all, your code is easier if you always use an indirect call.

Comment: By indirect call you mean move the offset to a register and call the register, right?

Comment: Or maybe a better question would be "Can I call an address directly?" and by "directly" I mean without calc-ing the displacement, but just doing something like ```call 0x87654321abcdefff``` ?

Comment: The `call` variants are described in the [documentation](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Comment: Ok, so according to that doc and http://ref.x86asm.net/geek.html I need ```REX.W + FF /3```, which translates (if I'm reading the docs right) to ```48 FF <something>```. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Why don't use use a (dis)assembler?

Comment: You mean writing a simple "printk" code and disassemble it? Can you recommend me a good disassembler? (By "good" I mean something that will show me just the code I'm interested in, not the entire binary)

Comment: An assembler like `gas`. For simple disassembling, `od` works just fine.

Comment: iirc ```od``` just dumps files, doesn't disassemble. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `objdump`.

Comment: Oh, ok, I thought so :)  Ok, let's see if I can get up to either indirect calls or direct far calls working

Answer (score 2):

The first thing which strikes me is the 'call' instruction. It's mostly zeros. That doesn't look like the address for printk.

What I think is happening here is that you compiled (or assembled) those instructions but did not link them. While compiling/assembling the compiler will happily create jump instructions to call functions defined in other files, but it can't possibly know where those functions will end up in the final binary. That's up to the linker.

You never ran a linker, so the destination for the call instruction was never resolved, and you're looking at a call to NULL.

As for a fix, if this is just an experiment I'd be inclined to just manually look up the address for printk (System.map might help there) and use that one.

Edit:

The kernel error says 'invalid opcode', so clearly something's wrong with the instructions you're generating. It's apparently unhappy about a 0 byte somewhere.

Try printing the address of 'bytecode'. The instruction pointer should point a few bytes past that, which might help you pinpoint the exact instruction which is failing.

Comment: No, the 'call' instruction is filled with the address of printk at line 63, ```memcpy(bytecode + pos, &printk, sizeof(void *));```.

Comment: Can you add the kernel panic message as well? That usually contains a lot of information about what's actually happening.

Comment: I updated the code and added the kernel oops, please have a look :)